# magento 1.9.2.1 import images using the csv

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.9

I am trying to import product using csv in magento 1.9.2.1. everything works fine but images is not showing in backend. I tried by uploading the images in the media/import folder and giving the path in csv as /imagename.jpg. but its not working.

Comment: Clear caches and then check.

Comment: i have done that but no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done it. i just deleted the column small_image, thumbnail, image.
and now it works fine.

Comment: If you deleted small_image, thumbnail and image - what Column did you then use to import the image for the products?

Comment: '_media_image' inserted the image path in this column